# Replacement has more rows than data in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

First, I do realize that there is a question with a similar title, but it didn't seem to solve my problem.

I am simply trying to build a logarithmic stock price index with log base 10 with a for loop like this:

```
t <- nrow[dat]

dat$logind <- matrix(NA, t, 1)
dat$logind[1] <- 100

for (i in 2:t) {
  dat$logind[i] <- (dat$logind[i-1] * (1+dat$logr[i])) 
}
```

`dat` is the dataframe, `logind` is just a column that I created to hold the index, and `logr` has the logarithmic returns. However, this throws me the following:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "logind", value = c(100, 99.3891882,  : 
  replacement has 1155 rows, data has 1154
```

I read that this error could be solved with using another way to select the column like `dat[,column]` but how do I use this when I already have `[i]` there? Or if you have another solution to this problem. Thanks.

Comment: didn't you mean `t <- nrow(dat)` instead of `t <- nrow[dat]`?

Comment: Well, that was simple, now I'm embarrassed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant `t <- nrow(dat)` instead of `t <- nrow[dat]`. Using `t` as variable name can be dangerous because you're overwriting function `t` (matrix/vector transpose).

You can get rid of your `for` loop by using R vectorized operators, like this:

```
dat$longind <- c(100, dat$logind[1:(nrow(dat)-1)] * (1+dat$logr[-1])) )
```